# SFTP with SharePoint when live over the internet

Tags: sharepoint, moss

We are using MOSS 2007.

We are about to make one of our SharePoint sites live over the internet but we wants the file upload/download to be SFTP. Is this possible in SharePoint, if so how can this be done? Must it be done through custom code (Please provide me with an example) or is there a setting somehwere where you can turn uploads and download of the site to SFTP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well SharePoint does not use FTP at all. It's files are being stored directly to database so there is no need for FTP.

By default it uses HTTP/HTTPS for file upload/download from web and WebDAV in case you are using multiple upload / explorer view.

In case you want to protect your files I would advise publishing your site via HTTPS only.

Answer (score 0):

As Toni said there is no FTP or SFTP server in SharePoint (these are very different protocols).

SFTP is based on the SSH protocol which provides a similar kind of protection to what HTTPS provides. So you may be able to meet your needs by using HTTPS.  You can configure this in Central Administration.

HTTPS is a lower level protocol than HTTP, and will protect both SharePoint HTTP and WebDAV traffic.

If you must use SFTP for some reason (for example integration with Unix-based systems perhaps) then you would need to run an SFTP server on the same server as SharePoint and create some mechanism for transferring these files into SharePoint. The file download process will not by fixed by this approach.